# Listen to a div change in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a case where a user can close a page in my react webapp, and i want to show a popup if changed has been made "Are you sure you want to close the page". To be clear i'm not talking about a web browser page, but a page/tab in my app.

Everything is set up and working using a button to simulate changes. The problem is i just want to find a way to listen to an entire div if there were change in it the DOM, in order to not put an action in every input of this div. If someone know a good way to do that i'll be glad to hear it. Thanks in advance.

(I use the js library lodash, but didn't find anything that helped me, but maybe i passed it too quickly).

EDIT
example of the div :

```
<div>
    <input value="Bob">
    <input value="Brian">
    <input value="Anna">
</div>
```

I want to know when user change the input

Comment: What do you mean with "listening to a div"? Which kind of change do you want to listen to? Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: Perhaps you could break your `div`into a component and use its `componentDidUpdate` lifecyle hook to "watch" for changes

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer !

@trixn it's a div with multiple input inside, i'm not sure that it's relevant if i put all the code here (quit big), let's just say i have a div with 3 input inside and want to know if the user change those input in the dom. (i will edit and add this example)

Comment: @t3__rry if i could avoid to make a component from that i would prefer to, it's a code i inherited and the div is quit massive with already component inside it

Comment: @RaphaelABADIE-MOREAU Are you using Redux?

Comment: @t3__rry yes, i'm using redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an on change handler to each input that you care about that updates the main component state on each input change and then when the user wants to close the window just check that state. like so:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state ={ inputsChanged: false}
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.onLeaveCheck = this.onLeaveCheck.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(){
   if(!this.state.inputsChanged){this.setState({inputsChanged: true})}
  }

  onLeaveCheck(){
   this.state.inputsChanged && window.alert('Are you sure you want to 
   leave)
  }

  render(){
    <div>
     <button onClick={this.onLeaveCheck} >X</button>
     <input  onChange={this.handleChange} />
     <input  onChange={this.handleChange} />
     <input  onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Another option for you is to set an interval with a function that will grab all the inputs by ids (or any other selector) and constantly check if their values changed and in case they did change, update change the component state just as above. If you are going in this route dont forget to remove the interval on componentWillUnmount.

Comment: I think i will have to go with the onChange on every input. I wanted to know if it was possible to listen to all the div to be sure not to forget something and for cleaner code but can't find a solution that does not include a modification on all the input

Comment: You can nest all inputs inside a form and just listen to the Form changes, this is the only other way i can think of that will allow you to listen to all children without explicitly putting an on change function on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a mouse leave event you can use this :

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
  }

  mouseLeave(){
       // your logic here
  }

  render(){
    <div  onMouseLeave={this.mouseLeave}>
      <input value="Bob">
      <input value="Brian">
      <input value="Anna">
    </div>
  }
}
```